# ошибка OSError: [WinError 193] %1 не является приложением Win32

Tags: python

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 не является приложением Win32. Error loading "C:\Users\gilma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\caffe2_detectron_ops.dll" or one of its dependencies.

повторял все по гайду https://habr.com/ru/post/506166/
[image: .]

Comment: Попробуйте добавить флаг `FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.